# how to call a native method with user defined datatypes as its parameters from java?

Tags: java, java-native-interface, native

i have a native method with user defined datatypes(structure) as the parameters.How do i call this method from java using JNI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a method like this:

```
int cFunction(mydatatype data) ...
```

You cannot call it directly. You will need a layer of JNI to glue it together.

---

So a JNI function is someting generated from your code:

```
class JavaTest {
    public native int jMethod(int a);
}
```

Running `javah` on that class you would get a header file like this:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_Javatest_jMethod(JNIEnv*, jobject obj, jint a);
```

Implementing that method to call `cFunction(mydatatype)`:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_Javatest_jMethod(JNIEnv*, jobject obj, jint a) {
    mydatatype data;
    data.count = a;
    return (jint) cFunction(data);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response.first of all may i know the native declaration for this method.suppose the method signature is int Cmethod(mydatatype m),where mydatatype is a structure of C.

Comment: @dacwe: Can you elaborate a bit more? (for that example: C-struct as parameter).

Comment: for that i need to create java class with the same members of the structure mydatatype.am i correct?

Comment: yes,i'll. i have a method which is expecting a structure and returns an integer.now i want to call this method from java using JNI.how do i send parameter for this method from java side?

Comment: can't we call that method directly from java?

Comment: No, you cannot, not using standard java tools. You can however have a look at [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna).

Comment: what if the return type is again an user defined datatype(an instance of mydatatype) instead of int.

Comment: You will need to transform `mydatatype` to a java object (using jni calls). I think you should check out JNA, it has much of you want, but you will need an "extra" library.

Comment: @dacwe no i dont want to use JNA,because my task includes some of the C++ classes also,so i have to use only JNI.

Comment: Check out my [previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324819/pass-data-between-java-and-c/4325678#4325678).

Comment: @dacwe may i know what is the significance of 'int a' in the following public native int jMethod(int a); declaration?

Comment: `int a` is passed to the c function as the argument `jint a`.

Comment: @dacwe so we have pass all the values for the structure members from java side,am i correct?

Comment: @dacwe thanks for your patience,one more thing what if i have self referential pointer as one of the member of the structure(mydatatype) of C.

Comment: You can do what ever you want with it... initialize it on the c-side, and if you want initialize it on the java-side.

Comment: can you please elaborate it?suppose i have a structure              typedef struct
     {
       int a;
       int b;
       mydatatype * block;
     } mydatatype; now waht should i pass from java side.

Comment: Sorry, this is just absurd... please, next time give full details when posting a question.

Comment: @johnkrishna: I'll undelete my answer, but next time write a new question with the new details.

Comment: @dacwe thank you very much.ok next time onwards i'll post full details in my question.

Answer (score 2):

There's way to read a java object fields:

```
jint _JMETHODNAME(MyClass,myMethod) (JNIEnv *env, jclass jcMyClass, jobject joMyObject)
{
    //Get the class
    jcMyObjectClass = env->FindClass("test/native/MyObject");
    if (jtException = env->ExceptionOccurred()) 
    {
        //Error management
    }
    if (jcMyObjectClass == NULL) 
    {
        //Error management
    }

    //Check if the class matchs the object
    jboolean jbFlag = env->IsInstanceOf(joMyObject,jcMyObjectClass);
    if (jtException = env->ExceptionOccurred()) 
    {
        //Error management
    }
    if (jbFlag == JNI_FALSE) 
    {
        //Error management
    }

    //Get a field
    jfieldID jfIdentField = env->GetFieldID(jcMyObjectClass,"fieldName","Ljava/lang/String;");
    if (jtException = env->ExceptionOccurred())
    {
        //Error management
    }
    if (jfIdentField == NULL) 
    {
        //Error management
    }

    //Read a field
    jstring jsMyString = (jstring)env->GetObjectField(joMyObject,jfIdentField);
    if (jtException = env->ExceptionOccurred()) 
    {
        //Error management
    }
    if (jsMyString == NULL) 
    {
        //Error management
    }

    //Convert to C++ format
    LPCTSTR strMyString = (LPTSTR)env->_tGetString(jsMyString, NULL);
    jsize myStringLen = env->_tGetStringLength(jsMyString);
    if (strMyString == NULL) 
    {
        //Error management
    }   
}
```

So you can use a Java Object as parameter and convert it to a C structure if you want.

Maybe this helps you.

For a selfreferenced object you can go through all of them like this:

```
//Get a field
jfieldID jfIdentField = env->GetFieldID(jcMyObjectClass,"selfReference","test/native/MyObject");
if (jtException = env->ExceptionOccurred())
{
    //Error management
}
if (jfIdentField == NULL) 
{
    //Error management
}

//Read a field
jobject joNextMyObject = (jstring)env->GetObjectField(joMyObject,jfIdentField);
if (jtException = env->ExceptionOccurred()) 
{
    //Error management
}
while (joNextMyObject != NULL) 
{
    //Process object

    //Read a field
     joNextMyObject = (jstring)env->GetObjectField(joNextMyObject,jfIdentField);
    if (jtException = env->ExceptionOccurred()) 
    {
        //Error management
    }
}
```

Comment: what if i have self referential pointer as one of the member of the structure of C.

Comment: You can have a self referential object in java as well, and go through it

Comment: I put direct fields access because is simplier, but you can use methods as well if you want