# Return object from java native method

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I would like to call a method through a native java interface, which returns an object.

This is my native method

```
public native Node getProjectionPoint(double lat, double lon);
```

Node class

```
 public class Node {        
    private String id;
    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;
}
```

C header file

```
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_org_smartcar_serverdatainterface_shared_services_CppConnector_getProjectionPoint (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jdouble lat, jdouble lon);
```

How could I create an object and return it to java?

Comment: Take a look to : http://stackoverflow.com/a/4325678/3315914

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I sort out the problem

```
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_org_smartcar_serverdatainterface_shared_services_CppConnector_getProjectionPoint
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jdouble lat, jdouble lon)
{
    jclass class = (*env)->FindClass(env,"org/smartcar/serverdatainterface/shared/businessentities/Node");

    if (NULL == class)
        PrintError ("class");

    jmethodID cid = (*env)->GetMethodID(env,class, "<init>", "(DD)V");

   if (NULL == cid)
       PrintError ("method");

   return (*env)->NewObject(env, class, cid, lat, lon);
}
```

this works perfectly

Answer (score 3):

In JNI you have a method

JNIEnv->NewObject() that invokes the actual constructor of a given Java class.

Maybe something like:

```
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_org_smartcar_serverdatainterface_shared_services_CppConnector_getProjectionPoint (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jdouble lat, jdouble lon)
{
  jclass cls = env->GetObjectClass(obj);
  jmethodID constructor = env->GetMethodID(cls, "<init>", "(DD)V");
  return env->NewObject(cls, constructor, lat, lon);
}
```

You should modify your class constructor to receive two parameters. You can also initialize field by field, but it requires to invoke GetFieldID two times in C++.

Comment: Buff... Maybe it's better to copy it, don't you think?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question; I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: I'm getting this error "error: request for member 'GetObjectClass' in something not a structure or union"

Comment: Are you including jni.h ?

Comment: i think this is the correct way "jclass cls = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, obj);"  :P

Comment: @JanithOCoder Your question is tagged C++ but you've discovered the C syntax. Either would work if you are compiling as C++ instead of C.

Comment: `GetObjectClass` would work in this case because the method is an instance method in the same class as the object to be created. I would find it confusing. `FindClass` is clearer.